# Wordpress install on LAMP not displaying on LAN properly

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, server, lamp

I've been trying to a website following this [Build a LAMP Web Server with WordPress](https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/lamp-web-server-with-wordpress) guideline. After completing the "WordPress configuration," the WordPress turn out fine on the local host but not another computer on the same network. Image provided.

[image]

Anything help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: make sure your site and home page path is set properly, also share the errors from console.

Answer (score 0):

Hope! You are accessing wordpress project with

```
http://localhost/wordpress-project/
```

And while accessing on other computer under same LAN. If you are trying to access with **localhost** that will not work. Because apache will look this request locally.

And if you are trying to access this with the LAN computer name/IP. like

```
http://192.168.0.106/wordpress-project/
OR
http://mycomputer1/wordpress-project/
```

Then you need to change the **siteurl** & **home** value in wordpress-project DB table named **wp_options** from localhost to desired.

**If you are accessing with computer name then you may need to set virtual host for that on mycomputer1 PC**